How should complementary tags be handled?
Consider unpacking versus packer. I think we should either stick to naming the entity (noun) or the method (verb) and there should be one covering the topic and its complement for something like the above.
And no, I don't mean to imply that you create bugging as a complementary tag for debuggers ;) ... sorry, couldn't resist.

See also: http://meta.reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/46/36

@amccormack: thanks for the link!

If we take the approach of only one tag, we should make the default the side that is used when actually reverse engineering. So in this case, we should use unpacking which could additionaly cover packing.
